# loading components when button clicked

Tags: reactjs

How would I be able to load a component when a button is pressed on the navbar component and loading it to the home page component. I wanted to load a  component on the homepage. I am using react route.Navbar component has a profile link which goes to profile component which has a form.

Navbar component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";

class Navbar extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: "",
      email: ""
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const token = localStorage.usertoken;
    const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
    this.setState({
      name: decoded.name,
      email: decoded.email
    });
  }
  logOut(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    localStorage.removeItem("usertoken");
    this.props.history.push("/");
  }
  render() {
    return (
      // const loginRegLink = (
      <div>
        <ul
          style={navBarStyle}
          id="sidenav-1"
          className="sidenav sidenav-fixed"
        >
          <li>
            <Link to={"/profile"}>
              <i class="material-icons ">person</i>
            </Link>
          </li>

          <li>
            <Link to={"/searchCourses"}>
              <i class="material-icons">search</i>
            </Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="" onClick={this.logOut.bind(this)}>
              <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt" />
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Homepage component

```
  class Homepage extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    document.title = "Dashboard";
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar />
        <div className="container">
          <div>
            <h3>Dashboard</h3>
            <hr />
          </div>
          <div className="col" />

        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Homepage;
```

Comment: Can you update postwith <Navbar /> component code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass a callback function to the Navbar and call her when the Navbar link is clicked.

```
      class Homepage extends Component {
      componentDidMount() {
        document.title = "Dashboard";
      }
    handleLinkClick()=>{
      //Function which you want to use in Navbar to select the right thing to render.You can use it in Navbar now. 
      //You should attach some value to it so you can determine which link was pressed like this: this.props.onLinkClick(value)
    }
      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <Navbar onLinkClick={this.handleLinkClick} />
            <div className="container">
              <div>
                <h3>Dashboard</h3>
                <hr />
              </div>
              <div className="col" />

            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
    export default Homepage;
```